# AWS SQS queue based load leveling

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-serverless

I am new to AWS Lambda and I have a scenario where I need to have the producer return data back to the consumer after processing and the consumer to the client. How can I go about this?

I have managed to send data to the consumer from the producer using the NodeJS stack.

Comment: If the producer needs to know the result of the computation that the consumer performs, then your architecture may not be the most straight forward.  You mention "load leveling" as the justification for using a queue, but AWS Lambda will autoscale and distribute load to your cloud functions for you, so you could use an HTTP trigger and have your producer directly call via HTTP instead of your producer indirectly call your consumer via an SQS queue trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Matthew. I tried to use the HTTP approach however when load testing this approach is not as effective under 1000 VUs so I thought having a queue in place would help unless you suggest otherwise.

Comment: Can you describe what the problem (and constraints) you're encountering?  Is the work some background job where the work is done asynchronously?  What's an acceptable amount of time to wait for the work to be done?  AWS Lambda has a lot of configurability in terms of its scaling behaviour.

Comment: The services need to scale and process requests at high values, currently when load testing I keep receiving "endpoint request timeout" error. Service A requests service B which leverages Redis but when under 1000 Vus Redis does not scale even after adding extra nodest we can not afford request drop-offs. Both of these services use AWS Lambda. –